# Add Continue Shopping button to woocommerce cart page, left side of update cart

Tags: woocommerce

Using this snippet will add Continue shopping button to cart page. What i don't understand is that its placed after update cart, i would like to show it before the update cart button.

```
    // Back to store button in cart
if (!function_exists('return_to_shop_cart_btn')) {
    function return_to_shop_cart_btn() {
        $shop_page_url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
        echo '<a class="link-to-shop" href="'.esc_url($shop_page_url).'" rel="nofollow">'.esc_html__('Continue Shopping', 'woocommerce').'<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_cart_actions', 'return_to_shop_cart_btn');
}
```

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOoAF.jpg)

Comment: This is because the hook is located just after the button, see https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/29b8b0d60d77c632c87bf52a638936112bf6f6f5/templates/cart/cart.php#L148-L150. 
One way is to overwrite the template file and change position

Comment: Ah your right! thank you